# angular route path with parameters separated with &amp;

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, url, angular-routing

This type of path is not working:

```
{ path: 'account/finalize?user=:user&token=:token', component: MyComponent }
```

I get route not found error when I access http://localhost:4200/account/finalize?user=devanshu&token=122323

But this is working:

```
{ path: 'account/finalize/:school/:token', component: MyComponent }
```

So, I can access http://localhost:4200/account/finalize/devanshu/122323

What is the problem here? Why is there an error in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
path: 'account/finalize'
```

and send user and token as query Params when navigating

```
this.router.navigate(['/account/finalize'], { queryParams: { user: 'user', token: 'your token' } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to pass these parameters:
`user=:user&token=:token`

You can get these parameters in the `req.body`

And if there is any particular component then you have to place the condition within the function.

Comment: can you give an example of how the URL would look

Comment: i think he is using that for account validation not for authentication

Comment: You can check here : https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Here is the example under "Accessing Query Param Values"

Comment: thanks, for the link @EitBiz it helped me understand what Fateh was saying

Comment: Great :) Support our answer